# Setting a NULL date

Tags: sql, vb.net, entity-framework

I have a date field in my database that is set when a customer is set to inactive when a user clicks a button to deactivate them. I am having trouble trying to figure out how to clear out the  inactive date when a user tries to reactive the customer.

This is what the deactivate button code looks like:

```
Private Sub btnDeactivate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeactivate.Click
        Dim selectedCustomers = GetSelectedCustomers()
        Dim newInActiveFlag = Not selectedCustomers.Any(Function(c) (c.Inactive_Flag = "Y"))
        Dim activateWord = "Activate"
        If newInActiveFlag Then
            activateWord = "Deactivate"
        End If

        Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Are you sure you want to {0} this Customer?", activateWord.ToLower()), activateWord + " Customer", _
                                                     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then

            Dim selectedCustomerIds = selectedCustomers.Select(Function(c) (c.Cust_Num))

            Dim service = New DataService()

            service.Customers.SetInactiveFlags(selectedCustomerIds, newInActiveFlag)
            service.SaveChanges()
            PerformSearch(_lastSearchTxt, _lastIncludeActive)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Here is the piece where it sets the inactive flag and date:

```
    Public Sub SetInactiveFlags(custIds As IEnumerable(Of Integer), inactiveFlag As Boolean)
        Dim customers As List(Of Customer)
        customers = _context.Customers.Where(Function(c) (custIds.Contains(c.Cust_Num))).ToList()

        For Each customer As Customer In customers
            customer.Inactive_Flag = CreateFromBoolean(inactiveFlag)
            customer.Inactive_Date = DateTime.Today
        Next

    End Sub
```

Is it possible to have the same button set and remove the date the same way I'm having it set and remove the inactive flag?

thanks

Comment: We cannot know the properties in your class Customers. But the code seems fine in case of having just two properties (Inactive_Flag and Inactive_Date); in case of having more properties (different for Inactive and for Active), you would have to change the SetInactiveFlags accordingly. Can you please explain the exact problem you are having now? How are you supposed to set/remove an inactive flag? Why is your code not working as expected now?

Comment: The problem that I'm having is that when I go to activate a customer it doesn't clear out the inactive date but instead inserts the date it was reactivated. To set/remove an inactive flag I use a single button who's text changes form "Deactivate" to "Activate" depending on if there is a "Y" or a "N" in the Inactive_Flag field and changes the value accordingly.

Comment: You just want to input a different date when it is deactivating? This is easy, just follow Tom's advice (set a nullable Date type and just pass Nothing when deactivating, via condition in SetInactiveFlags or argument as suggested by Tom); or create a "extreme date" (e.g., 1-1-1900) which will be used for deactivated cases, again via condition/argument in SetInactiveFlags.

Comment: No I want to to clear the date out completely when it is activating, it is already inserting a date when it is deactivating which is what I want.

Comment: "Clear completely" is not allowed in a standard Date type (having a date is required). You can convert the standard type, into nullable one (= accepting nulls/nothings/the closest thing to clear) and use Nothing with dates if you wish. This is what Tom's answer is about. If you cannot change the date type into a nullable one, you would have either to create an "extreme date" as suggested; or not rely on dates at all and rely on a different type supporting nulls/blanks by default (string, for example). If you don't understand exactly what Tom has suggested, perhaps you should ask him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you're allowing `null` values on your `Inactive_Date` field, you can simply set it to Nothing. If you change the SetInactiveFlags method to have a Nullable(Of DateTime) parameter (or shortcut it with DateTime? ala C#), you can pass it across directly:

```
Public Sub SetInactiveFlags(custIds As IEnumerable(Of Integer), inactiveDate As DateTime?, inactiveFlag As Boolean)
...
customer.Inactive_Date = inactiveDate
...
```

Then you can either use `SetInactiveFlags(selectedCustomerIds, Nothing, newInActiveFlag)` or `SetInactiveFlags(selectedCustomerIds, DateTime.Now, newInActiveFlag)`

The entity framework/Linq2Sql will automatically translate Nothing to DBNull.Value.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found a solution but have to wait 8 hours before I can post it since my reputation is less than 10. I'll make sure to post it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I found Solution, I took Tom's advice and added this to the btn click event:

```
If activateWord = "Deactivate" Then
                service.Customers.SetInactiveFlags(selectedCustomerIds, DateTime.Today, newInActiveFlag)
            ElseIf activateWord = "Activate" Then
                service.Customers.SetInactiveFlags(selectedCustomerIds, Nothing, newInActiveFlag)
            End If
```

so the full piece looks like this:

```
    Private Sub btnDeactivate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeactivate.Click
        Dim selectedCustomers = GetSelectedCustomers()
        Dim newInActiveFlag = Not selectedCustomers.Any(Function(c) (c.Inactive_Flag = "Y"))
        Dim activateWord = "Activate"
        If newInActiveFlag Then
            activateWord = "Deactivate"
        End If

        Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Are you sure you want to {0} this Customer?", activateWord.ToLower()), activateWord + " Customer", _
                                                     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then

            Dim selectedCustomerIds = selectedCustomers.Select(Function(c) (c.Cust_Num))

            Dim service = New DataService()
            If activateWord = "Deactivate" Then
                service.Customers.SetInactiveFlags(selectedCustomerIds, DateTime.Today, newInActiveFlag)
            ElseIf activateWord = "Activate" Then
                service.Customers.SetInactiveFlags(selectedCustomerIds, Nothing, newInActiveFlag)
            End If
            service.SaveChanges()
            PerformSearch(_lastSearchTxt, _lastIncludeActive)
        End If
    End Sub
```

I also changed the SetInactiveFlags to look like this:

```
    Public Sub SetInactiveFlags(custIds As IEnumerable(Of Integer), Inactive_Date As DateTime?, inactiveFlag As Boolean)
        Dim customers As List(Of Customer)
        customers = _context.Customers.Where(Function(c) (custIds.Contains(c.Cust_Num))).ToList()

        For Each customer As Customer In customers
            customer.Inactive_Flag = CreateFromBoolean(inactiveFlag)
            customer.Inactive_Date = Inactive_Date
        Next

    End Sub
```

I took me a minute to understand the logic but thanks for taking the time to help me I really appreciate it.